# Java String to replace a word from a String

Tags: java, collections

Can you please provide a best solution for the below scenario in Java code

```
I have a String like below

String str1= "insert into CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER.Name, CUSTOMER.Age, CUSTOMER.city) values ('ASAL',22,'New Yark')"
String str1 = "insert into CUSTOMER(Customer.Name, Customer.Age, Customer.city) values ('Thangam',23,'Sane')"
```

In this String i need to remove the table name alone where tablename is appended with column name. My output should be like below

```
String str1= "insert into CUSTOMER(Name, Age, city) values ('ASAL',22,'New Yark')"
String str1 = "insert into CUSTOMER(Name, Age, city) values ('Thangam',23,'Sane')"
```

Please note in one scenario tablename is as "CUSTOMER" and one scenaro as "Customer".

Can you please provide a best function/solution to solve this.

Comment: `str1 = str1.replace("CUSTOMER.", "");`

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("(?i)\\bCUSTOMER\\.", "");
```

This uses case-insensitive `(?i)`, a word boundary `\b` and escapes `.`.

By the way, a PreparedStatement on placeholders might simplify things

```
String str1 = "insert into CUSTOMER(Name, Age, city) values (?,?,?)";
```

Besides taking care of malicious data entry it escapes names like `d'Artagnan`.